# how can i retreve multiple values from mysql with php jquery and ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

im trying out something new for me that's working with a MySQL database using PHP and Ajax to retrieve multiple data to a HTML page on loading.

HTML:

```
 <div id="name">Mark</div>
 <br/>
 <input id="realcost" value=""></input>
 <p id="size"></p>
 <div id="#desc">description</div>
```

Jquery:

```
function get() {
$.getJSON('data.php', {
    name: $("#name").text()
}, function(data) {
    $("input#realcost").val(data.cost);
    $("p#size").text(data.size);
    $("#desc").text(data.details);
    'json'
});
}
get();
```

what it dose is gets the text from name pass it to data.php and retrieves the values #realcost, #size and #desc

PHP:

```
 <?php
 mysql_connect( "localhost", "username", "password");
 $name = mysqul_real_escape_string ($_POST['name']);
 $cost = mysql_qery ("SELECT cost FROM list.itemlist WHERE name='$name'");
 $size = mysql_qery ("SELECT size FROM list.itemlist WHERE name='$name'");
 $details = mysql_qery ("SELECT details FROM list.itemlist WHERE name='$name'");
 echo json_encode(array("cost" => $cost, "size" => $size, "details" => $details));

 ?>
```

don't know why i cant retrieve data into these feel's.

Comment: You have a typo.  `mysql_qery` should be `mysql_query`

Comment: That probably because you get fatal php errors?

Check your spelling of your funciton names: `mysql_query`, `mysqul_real_escape_string` ->  `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: There is a syntax error with the string "json" in your jquery function. It's placed wrong.

Comment: Use a the development tools that come with your browser (or firebug) to monitor headers & responses. Also run the php script directly before using ajax to make sure it is working correctly. You would then see that you are getting fatal errors

Comment: @radashk, theres no syntax error, but yes there is a stray `json`, don't know why its there, but its harmless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
 mysql_connect( "localhost", "username", "password");
 $name = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['name']);
$query = "SELECT cost, size, details FROM list.itemlist where name='$name'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($query));

 echo json_encode(array("cost" => $row['cost'], "size" => $row['size'], "details" => $row['details']));

 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is so much wrong with that code, it's hard to see where to start.

But assuming that you get your syntax errors fixed in the php file, you actually need to retrieve rows after you make an sql query, something like `$name_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($name);`.

And I would recommend switching to PDO or mysqli.

And of course you can get all information in just one query...

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using from a wrong function 'mysql_qery'.

See this:

```
ini_set("display_errors", true);
mysql_connect( "localhost", "username", "password");
$name = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['name']);
$cost = mysql_query ("SELECT cost FROM list.itemlist WHERE name='$name'");
$size = mysql_query ("SELECT size FROM list.itemlist WHERE name='$name'");
$details = mysql_query ("SELECT details FROM list.itemlist WHERE name='$name'");
echo json_encode(array("cost" => $cost, "size" => $size, "details" => $details));
```

use this line to ensure that errors will be shown:

```
ini_set("display_errors", true);
```

And then use firebug (Addon for mozilla firefox) to see the output of your php file and check errors.

Your has some errors with getting data.
see this function,maybe help...:

```
function getAllDATA($user, $pass, $host, $name = '')
{
    $conn = mysql_connect($user, $pass, $host);

    if (!$conn)
        return false;

    //@mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8' "); if you are using utf8 data

    $dbName = "DatabaseName");
    if (!mysql_select_db($dbname))
        return false;


    $data = array();

    $q = "SELECT cost FROM list.itemlist WHERE name='$name'";

    //echo $q;

    $result = mysql_query($q);

    //echo mysql_error();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        $data[] = $row;

    mysql_close($conn);

    self::$data = $data;

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: You didn't fix all the spelling mistakes.

Comment: Also jeroen is very correct that there are more mistakes in there, with the way the data is fetched. Hard to see through all the spelling mistakes...